# Assign textbox values with ajax - page still refreshing and assigned values are gone

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to fill a part of my web page by using AJAX instead of C# since the webpage should not be refreshed for this action. All I need to do is to run a SELECT query and get the current client from SQL DB and fill the related form without refreshing the page. I managed to get the related client and to change the related textbox, however, the page is still refreshing and all the textboxes becomes null again!

My code is on the below:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlClientSummaryDetails" runat="server" Width="360px" Visible="True">
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateOpened"></asp:TextBox>
       <!--other text boxes -->
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID="bnSelectClient" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style7" Text="Select Client" ToolTip="Click the view client button to view selected clients information" Width="282px" OnClientClick="BindClientSummaryForm()" />

    function BindClientSummaryForm() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Clients.aspx/GetClientSummaryData",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('<%= txtDateOpened.ClientID %>').value = data.d.DateFileOpened;
                  // other textboxes will be filled like that.
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error occured while filling ClientSummary part.");
                }
            });
        }

[WebMethod] 
        public static MyClient GetClientSummaryData() //GetData function
        {
            //FillClientSummaryGridView();
            int intClientID = 0; 
            Int32.TryParse(clientID, out intClientID);
            MyClient client = new MyClient();
            string sQuery = "SELECT ClientID,FirstName,DateFileOpened FROM dbo.Client where ClientID = " + intClientID;
            String sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDatabase"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtGetData = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtGetData);

            foreach(DataRow dtRow in dtGetData.Rows)
            {
                client.Firstname = dtRow.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                client.DateFileOpened = dtRow.ItemArray[2].ToString();            
            }
            return client;
        }
```

What should I do friends? I have to prevent page refreshing and keep the textbox values that assigned by success part of the ajax. Thank you!

Comment: Side note, using WebMethod isn't recommended anymore, Microsoft doesn't support it. Instead, new development should be done using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add return false to your BindClientSummaryForm function after the ajax call, also modify the way you are calling the function to this: OnClientClick="return BindClientSummaryForm();"

If that does not work, try removing return false from the function and using this instead: OnClientClick="BindClientSummaryForm(); return false;"

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.function BindClientSummaryForm() {
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
        return false;
    }

Comment: please also modify the way you are calling the function to this:

return BindClientSummaryForm();